# Where is the sqlite3.connection.__init__ method documented?

Tags: python, sqlite

The post's title says it all.

---

AFAICT, neither [the fine manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#connection-objects) nor the [Python DB API](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#connection-objects) says *anything at all* about, or pertaining to, `sqlite3.connection.__init__`.  *Please correct me if I'm wrong!*

(I find it inexplicable that such a gaping hole in the documentation could have persisted as long as this.)

Also, AFAICT this method is not implemented in Python, so looking at the Python source for it is not an option.

Finally,

```
In [2]: import inspect

In [3]: inspect.getmro(sqlite3.Connection)
Out[3]: (sqlite3.Connection, object)
```

IOW, the class's superclass (`object`) sheds no light on the question.

Comment: Are connections supposed to be constructed manually? Normally they're returned pre-made from somewhere else, no?

Comment: From the very first example in the manual: `conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')`

Comment: @JohnGordon: if you think that examples = documentation, then we have *very different* ideas as to what the word "documentation" means.  Not to mention the fact that I'm asking about `sqlite3.connection.__init__`, and not about `sqlite3.connect`.  If the two are related, the fact is not self-evident, and needs to be documented as well.

Comment: @Cameron: see my comment in response to chepner's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create the connection object manually. Use [`sqlite3.connect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect) instead. The `__init__` method itself should be considered an implementation detail, rather than something to be used directly.

Comment: The documentation [explicitly says](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect) (or, rather, grunts incoherently to the effect) that if one wants to modify the way `sqlite3.connect` is done, one should subclass `sqlite3.Connection` and use that instead.  In order to subclass `sqlite3.Connection` I need to know `sqlite3.Connection.__init__`'s signature.

Comment: Granted that the documentation could be better (it almost always can), if you're going to be subclassing things, surely it's a good idea to look at the source of the class you're subclassing?